# How to set union's field using template

Tags: c++, templates

my code looks like that:

```
typedef enum {STR, INT, FLOAT} Type;
struct MyStruct
{
   Type type;
   union
   {
       std::string str;
       int i;
       float f;
   } value;    
};
```

I'm trying to set Values inthat way:

```
template<typename T> void setValue(T data)
{
    switch(this->getType())
    {
        case Type::STR:
            this->str = data;
            break;
        case Type::INT:
            this->i = data;
            break;
        case Type::FLOAT:
            this->f = data;
            break;
        default:
            // Throw an exception
            break;
    }
}
```

So, in my opinion, all looks great, but i get an error (e.g. while int-value setting): myStructInstance.setValue< int >(10);

```
error: cannot convert ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘int’
```

Why? I want to set the int field, not the string.

Comment: All *branches* should be valid.

Comment: To elaborate on what Jarod42 said, when the function template is instantiated into an actual function, **all** the code inside it must be valid.

Comment: Your union seems strange: store a pointer on std::string instead of the variable. I don't know the bahaviour it has, but not convinced that it would work.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, that's c++11 and beyond. Quite well defined.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to name the union. The names of the members will be injected into the struct. Edit: it seems that you already do, since the code is written that way.

Answer (score 2):

As Jarod and StoryTeller said, all branches should be valid. You can pass by a template specialization :

```
template<typename T> void setValue(T data)
{
    switch(this->getType())
    {
    case Type::INT:
        this->i = data;
        break;
    case Type::FLOAT:
        this->f = data;
        break;
    default:
        // Throw an exception
        break;
    }
}

template<> void setValue(std::string data)
{
    switch(this->getType())
    {
    case Type::STR:
        this->str = data;
        break;
    default:
        // Throw an exception
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire body of your `setValue` function needs to type-check once the template is instantiated with some given type.

Instead of having one big function, you could use plain overloads:

```
void setValue(const std::string &data)
{
    if (this->getType() != Type::STR) {
      // Throw
    }
    this->value.str = data;
}

// dito for other Type values.
```